# angular 1.6: can't get to pass text to modal as component

Tags: angularjs, factory, angular-bootstrap

I have a factory:

```
  ngapp.factory('ErrorService',["$uibModal", function ErrorService($uibModal) {
    return {
      showError: function(errorText) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: true,
          component: 'errorDialog',
          resolve: {
                errorText: function () {
                    return errorText;
                }
            } 
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

a dialog, using the angular bootstrap Modal component:

```
angular.module('myapp').component('errorDialog', {
  templateUrl: 'errorDialog.html',
  controller: function ($scope) {

    $scope.title = "Something went wrong!";
    $scope.error = $scope.errorText || "Generic error";

    $scope.cancel = function () {
      this.dismiss({$value: 'cancel'});
    };
  }
});
```

...being this the template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="errorDialog.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>{{$title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="dialogBody">
    <div class="errorText">{{error}}
      <button class="btn btn-primary yes" type="submit" ng-click="cancel()">Ok</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

I can't get `error`to display my `errorText` when using it like this:

```
ErrorService.showError("Failed to connect.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add bindings to your modal component, and bind it to `$scope` again with `this.$onInit`, to make sure the binding happens *after* `resolve` has been.. resolved.

```
angular.module('myapp').component('errorDialog', {
  bindings: {
    resolve: '<',
    close: '&',
    dismiss: '&'
  },
  templateUrl: 'errorDialog.html',
  controller: function ($scope) {

    this.$onInit = function() {
      $scope.error = this.resolve.errorText;
    }
  }
});
```

---

Small recommendation, in your `component` you can add:

```
controllerAs: '$something',
controller: function() {

    // Bind it to this
    var $something = this;

    // Use $something instead of $scope from now on
    $something.text = 'Hello';

    // Or with resolve
    $something.$onInit = function() {
        $something.error = $something.resolve.errorText;
    }
}
```

And then, in your template, you can use:

```
<span>{{$something.error}}</span>
```

Which removes the need for `$scope` entirely, and makes debugging a lot easier, since everything is contained in it's own scope (in this case, your modal). You binded to `errorText` to `$scope`, but still, it was not available in your component. This can be very confusing.

It's really worth trying to use `$scope` as less as possible, before you end up with so called [Scope soup](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html).

Comment: Added a small recommendation for you

Comment: indeed I had mixed up code from different examples, but I finally resolved to use what you suggest - but I hadn't understood why! So thanks, very helpful recommendation.